# How do convert a block unsigned char* memory to a block of [signed] char* memory?

Tags: c++, objective-c, buffer, asihttprequest, soci

I'm working on an iPad project (iOS 5.1) which requires fetching images from a url and caching them as a sqlite3 blob. I'm using ASIHTTPRequest to fetch the image data and SOCI to insert the blob into the cache table. The project is written in C++ (mixed with minimal Objective-C).

The problem is that ASIHTTPRequest returns binary data via an NSData object ... from which I can acquire a const unsigned char* pointer. But SOCI's interface only provides an interface to read/write blob data via a char* pointer ... (SOCI internally writes the data to a char* buffer before opening/writing-to/reading-from a sqlite_blob).

So, the question then, is converting my unsigned char* buffer into a char* buffer a viable solution? ..and, if so, how do I do it? ..otherwise, what other options to I have to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

A simple casting will do the job:

```
(unsigned char *)myCharPointer
(char *)myUnsignedCharPointer
```

Comment: You will need to cast as `const char *`.

Comment: I used reinterpret_cast ... but, yeah, same difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what @Binyamin said, be sure to use memcpy, though so that you can know your buffer won't disappear:

```
uint8_t *origBuffer = [data bytes];
char *myBuffer = malloc([data length]);

memcpy(myBuffer, origBuffer, [data length]);

// don't forget to free 'myBuffer' when done!
```

Comment: The buffer should not disappear or become invalid unless a) you release `data` or pop an autorelease pool that it belongs to b) you mutate mutable `data`

Comment: @Joe exactly. It's always better to be safe than sorry when it comes to memory management.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I agree, but when working on devices with limited memory if you can guarantee `NSData` won't change then you would be fine. Otherwise I agree, better to be safe than sorry.